# Two entities should have same parent entity in relational model

Tags: database, model, entity, entity-relationship, relational

I have simple models: People, Photos, Pair of photos.

An instance of "Pair of photos" should be linked with two "Photo" instances which are linked with the same "Human" instance.

I tried to implement it using ER model. In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnhqb.png) case, "PhotoPair" can contain photos from different persons, so it is wrong.

So, how I can solve this problem? (without using triggers)

Comment: Firstly - remove the foreign key from person to photo_pair.  You already have implied that there ~can be~ more than one person based on the implications from photo's two contributions.  Unless there are actually 3 photo owners in each pair.  Secondly, there is no way based purely on constraints to say that the persons "owning" the individual photos in photo_pair are different.  I'm actually not sure why you are modelling this way to begin with.  Are there ALWAYS ONLY going to be "pairs" of photos?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There always will be pairs of photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got PersonID in PhotoPair, you can set up overlapping foreign key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE PhotoPair
ADD CONSTRAINT 'photo1_person_fk'
    FOREIGN KEY (Photo1, PersonID)
    REFERENCES Photo (PhotoID, PersonID),
ADD CONSTRAINT 'photo2_person_fk'
    FOREIGN KEY (Photo2, PersonID)
    REFERENCES Photo (PhotoID, PersonID);
```